# HighCharts turn animation false for line chart

Tags: graph, highcharts

I'm new to highCharts and want to know how I can turn off the animation for line charts.

I've tried setting it to false in plotlines but no success.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

It's the same that I answered [here](http://jsfiddle.net/huBLe/) but you have to change `column` to `line`.

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        animation: false
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ks87S/)

If you want to remove animation from all types you can use `series` instead.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like documentation needs updating http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation

Comment: You can just set `plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
}` now and that turns off line line chart animations too.

Comment: how to use it in swift , can you please help ?

Answer (score 18):

If you want to completely disable all animations in Highcharts (also these happening when toggling lines on or off) use the following:

```
chart: {
    animation: false
}
```

See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation for more information. (**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/animation-none/)**)

Comment: > The only animation not affected by this option is the initial series animation, see plotOptions.series.animation
So I believe this should work along with the `series` one in the other answer